# Can a website have 2 google webmaster tools on it?

Tags: google-search-console

I work in a corporate environment where I manage several websites.  Some websites that are in our system have been developed my an outside agency.  We are in the process of adding google webmaster tools to the sites.  However the outside agencies have already place google webmaster tools on the sites they've created.

Would there be an issue with a site having 2 google webmaster tools on it?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't because webmaster tools is connected to Google analytics code, and you can't have two GA code in your website.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!